# css border does not show up in table when adding to a div

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am adding a string table and adding it to a div in jQuery. Everything works, except the table border doesn't show. If I type the table directly into the div, then the CSS border works.

```js
var show = "<table class='tableNumbersChart'>";
show += "<tr>";
show += "<th colspan=4>Numbers</th>";
show += "</tr>";
show += "<tr>";
show += "<th>#</th>";
show += "<th>1</th>";
show += "<th>2</th>";
show += "<th>3</th>";
show += "</tr>";
show += "<tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td></tr>";
show += "</table>"

$('#displayNumbersChart').append(show);
```

```css
.tableNumbersChart {
  border: 1px;
  vertical-align: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.tableNumbersChart th {
  background-color: rgb(248, 159, 156);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="displayNumbersChart"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned any border type (solid, dashed etc) in the above css for table, th, td.

```
.tableNumbersChart {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
.tableNumbersChart th, td {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var show = "<table class='tableNumbersChart'>";
show += "<tr>";
show += "<th colspan=4>Numbers</th>";
show += "</tr>";
show += "<tr>";
show += "<th>#</th>";
show += "<th>1</th>";
show += "<th>2</th>";
show += "<th>3</th>";
show += "</tr>";
show += "<tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td></tr>";
show += "</table>"

$('#displayNumbersChart').append(show);

});
```

```css
.tableNumbersChart {
  border: 1px solid red;
  vertical-align: center;
  text-align: center;
}
.tableNumbersChart {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
.tableNumbersChart th {
   background-color: rgb(248, 159, 156);
}
.tableNumbersChart th, td {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="displayNumbersChart"></div>
```

Comment: The question doesn't mention cell borders--just the table border. Also, you've modified the original code, obscuring the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS `border` property is shorthand for multiple properties. As such, it expects a border type.

```js
var show = "<table class='tableNumbersChart'>";
show += "<tr>";
show += "<th colspan=4>Numbers</th>";
show += "</tr>";
show += "<tr>";
show += "<th>#</th>";
show += "<th>1</th>";
show += "<th>2</th>";
show += "<th>3</th>";
show += "</tr>";
show += "<tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td></tr>";
show += "</table>"

$('#displayNumbersChart').append(show);
```

```css
.tableNumbersChart {
  border: 1px dashed; /* <-- type needed */
  vertical-align: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.tableNumbersChart th {
  background-color: rgb(248, 159, 156);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="displayNumbersChart"></div>
```